Some confusion regarding the notions of in-boundary and out-boundary
Let $ M $ be a smooth manifold with boundary. Let's recall the following

Definition. A vector $ v\in \mathrm T_pM $ tangent to a point $ p\in \partial M $ is outward-pointing if $ v\not\in \mathrm T_p(\partial M) $, and for some $ \epsilon > 0 $ there is a curve $ c\colon \left]-\epsilon,0\right]\to M $ such that $ c(\left]-\epsilon,0\right[)\subset \operatorname{Int}M $ and $ c(0) = p $ that realizes $ v $ as the derivative $ v = \dot c(0) $. We say moreover that $ v $ is inward pointing if $ -v $ is outward pointing.

Given a point $ p\in \partial M $ and chosen a chart $ (U,\phi) $ around $ p $, the canonical basis $ \{\partial_1,\dots,\partial_{n - 1},\partial_n\} $ of $ \mathrm T_pM $ induced by $ (U,\phi) $ is subdivided as follows: $ \partial_1,\dots,\partial_{n - 1} $ are tangent to $ \partial M $ (i.e., $ \partial_\mu\in \mathrm T_p(\partial M) $), and $ \partial_n $ is always inward pointing.
Now, I read that given a manifold with boundary $ M $ (think of $ M $ as the product $ M = \Sigma\times \left[0,1\right] $ where $ \Sigma $ is some boundaryless manifold) we can classify the connected components of $ \partial M $ in the following way:

Definition. If $ \Sigma_j $ is a connected component, then we say that $ \Sigma_j $ is an in-boundary if given $ p\in \Sigma_j $ and picked some $ v\in \mathrm T_pM $ then $ v $ is inward pointing (in the same way we define out-boundaries).

Referring to the the paradigmatic case $ M = \Sigma\times \left[0,1\right] $ we will have
$$
\partial M = \Sigma_1\amalg \Sigma_2 = \left(\Sigma\times\{0\}\amalg \Sigma\times \{1\}\right)
$$
and $ \Sigma_1 $ is an in-boundary while $ \Sigma_2 $ is an out-boundary.
Now, I read that this notions of in-boundary and out-boundary are well defined, and I really believe that this is the case... if it were not for the fact that according to my definition of inward/outward pointing vectors every connected component of a boundary $ \partial M $ should be an in-boundary.
There's clearly something I have misunderstood. How do I solve this contradiction?
